# passing null parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I am currently having some trouble wrapping my head around this issue. I had a method that didn't require any parameters and now i need to add a parameter but i don't want to add the parameter in all the different places where the method is called. This is my current method :

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null)
    {
        IOrderedQueryable<ItemDescription> items= _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(
            c => c.Sort == null).ThenBy(
                c => c.Sort).ThenBy(c => c.Description);

        if(items.Count()==0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("No active {0} entered.", Kids.Resources.Entities.ItemDescription.EntityNamePlural));
       return
            _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(c => c.Description).Where(a=>a.IsActive == true || viewModel == null || a.ItemDescriptionId == viewModel.ItemDescriptionId).Select(
                c => new SearchItems {Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()});
    }
```

I tried passing in null as a parameter for the other places where this method is being called but i am getting an error. What is the way to overload this issue?

PURPOSE: The purpose of adding the viewModel is because i have a dropdown list with active items to choose from. Once a user selects an active item and then for some reason that item becomes inactive and the user goes to edit their selection. In the dropdown list there should be the list of active items along with their previous selected item that is now inactive. I am using the ViewModel to check the id of the previously selected item.

Thanks

Comment: @Amina: Is null a valid value for viewModel parameter?

Comment: @Dennis i had the parameter like so: ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null.

Comment: Is ItemDescriptionFormViewModel a class or a struct?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare ItemDescriptionFormViewModel is a class... I am currently testing suggested changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone... Thanks for all the help and effort in trying to resolve this issue. I was finally able to work around it and here is who i fixed my problem: [Checking List Item Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340156/checking-list-item-id)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a default value to `viewModel`:

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(
    ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null)
{
    if (viewModel == null) 
        viewModel = new ItemDescriptionFormViewModel();
```

This way, if you simply call `GetItems()`, it will treat `viewModel` as a `new ItemDescriptionFormViewModel()`.

Comment: When i tried this i got this error: Default parameter value for 'viewModel' must be a compile-time constant

Comment: So I think you have to use the default value `ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null` and test for the null case when comparing the values.

Comment: I did that which was also suggested by others but now i am getting an object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: :D The error message is gone but i am not getting what i want as a result. The whole idea of having the ViewModel is to check the id of a previously selected item and on an edit page it will be populated with the selected item but currently it is not showing that selected item because i made it inactive after selecting it. The purpose is once a user selects an item and then that item goes inactive, when the user goes to edit that item that it shows active items in the dropdown along with the inactive item that he selected previously.

Comment: I think the reason you don't get the right result is that since you create a `new ItemDescriptionFormViewModel()`, the ItemDescriptionID is set to 0 by default. You'll need to put a check on `ItemDescriptionID == 0` before checking the ID to execute the method as if there was no parameters.

Comment: The problem occurs when you call the function with or without a parameter? Because you can also "bypass" all the logic and return all the items if `viewModel == null`.

Comment: There isn't really a problem as much as i don't think that it is doing the where clause all the way. Its not getting item based on the id.

Comment: I think we all need to see the code of the function calling `GetItems`. Make another question (because I think it's a different problem from the one we discussed here), and put the link here! ;)

Comment: I posted a new question - take a look hopefully i don't sound confusing. Thanks a bunch Lucas for trying to help i really hope i could resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts so much! I was finally able to resolve the issue in my other question post and again thanks for all your help and time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340156/checking-list-item-id

Answer (score 0):

declare it like this:

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null)
```

and make sure to have a `null` check in your method, something like this:

```
return
        _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(c => c.Description).Where(a=> viewModel == null || (a.IsActive == true || a.ItemDescriptionId == viewModel.ItemDescriptionId)).Select(
            c => new SearchItems {Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()});
```

this will allow you to call the method using `GetItems()` and `GetItems(ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel)`

EDIT: Disregard ? since ItemDescriptionFormViewModel is a class

Comment: When i tried this i got an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. And it is referring to my .cshtml view page.

Comment: On what object do you get that error? Do you use viewModel elsewhere in the method?

Comment: The exact line is: self.items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Mode.Items));
In the method i currently have the only time i use the viewModel is just to check the Id of an item which i have in the code currently.

Comment: If you only use it to find an ID, you could just pass an int instead of the whole viewModel. Also, have you put the null check? It's essential for calling it with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're dereferencing a null reference here:

```
_itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll()
    .OrderBy(c => c.Description)
    .Where(a=>a.IsActive == true || 
        a.ItemDescriptionId == viewModel.ItemDescriptionId) // if viewModel null, this throws
    .Select(c => new SearchItems 
    {
        Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()
    });
```

So you could just update your `Where()` clause to add pass if the view model is null:

```
...
.Where(a => a.IsActive || viewModel == null || viewModel.ItemDescriptionId == a.ItemDescriptionId)
```

Then you can pass `null` as the argument safely, and you can even make a default parameter value so if no parameter is passed, it assumes the `null`.

This is, of course, assuming `ItemDescriptionFormViewModel` is a class, if it's a struct, then you'd have to make it nullable `ItemDescriptionFormViewModel?`

Comment: When i adjusted the code i get the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on my .cshtml view page.

Comment: @Amina: on what line?  That's the only place you use viewModel.  Can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: I updated my code to what i have. The exact error line is in my view page: self.items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items)); and the error message as i mentioned in my previous comment. I am somewhat confused with this error. Would showing my viewModel help any? I really appreciate the help - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both methods(I mean GetItems() and GetItems(viewModel)) they will automatically overload.

If you want the second method, you can pass parameter like this

```
 private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(ItemDescriptionFormViewModel? viewModel)
```

Now you can pass null as its parameter.

Comment: Only if `ItemDescriptionFormViewModel` is a value type, i.e. a struct. Also, you'll then need to remember to check `viewModel.HasValue`, if that returns true you can acess it's value with `viewModel.Value`.

Comment: This won't work for me cuz ItemDescriptionFormViewModel is a class.