# Checking List Item Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am trying to check a selected Item Id and display in dropdown list on an Edit page which will show the previous selected item. The Items show based on their active status. All active items are displayed in the dropdown and if the previous selection choice for the user is currently inactive, it should still default to that item in the dropdown list since it was the selection previously made. My issue is that i am not able to show the inactive item that was selected by the user on the edit page. I will post all my code and this is a continuation of a question asked in a different link: [passing null parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334582/passing-null-parameters)

my Code in CONTROLLER:

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(ItemDescriptionFormViewModel viewModel = null)
{
    if(viewModel == null)
      viewModel = new AppointmentViewModel();
    IOrderedQueryable<ItemDescription> items= _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(
        c => c.Sort == null).ThenBy(
            c => c.Sort).ThenBy(c => c.Description);

    if(items.Count()==0)
        ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("No active {0} entered.", Kids.Resources.Entities.ItemDescription.EntityNamePlural));
   return
        _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(c => c.Description).Where(a=>a.IsActive == true || a.ItemDescriptionId == viewModel.ItemDescriptionId).Select(
            c => new SearchItems {Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()});
}
```

My Edit Method in CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AppointmentAuthorization]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid appointmentId)
    {
        Appointment appointment = _appointmentService.Get(appointmentId);
        if (appointment == null) return View("NotFound");


        var viewModel = new AppointmentViewModel
                            {
                                AppointmentId = appointment.AppointmentId,

                            };
        viewModel.Items= GetItems();

        return this.RazorView("Edit", viewModel);
    }
```

It seems like something is missing and passing viewModel as a parameter in viewModel.Items= GetItems() didn't do much. I also have another Post method for Edit and a Create method all which call the GetItems() method. Any help will be great. Thanks :D

This is what i have in my ViewModel class:

```
public IEnumberable<SearchItems> Items {get; set;}
public Guid ItemDescriptionid {get; set;}
```

Create Method:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AppointmentAuthorization]
    public ActionResult Create(Guid caseId)
    {
        var viewModel = new AppointmentViewModel
                            {
                               Items= GetItems()
                            };

        return this.RazorView("Create", viewModel);
    }
```

*****SOLUTION*****

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(Appointment appointment)
    {
        IEnumerable<short?> itemDescriptionIds =
            appointment.AppointmentItems.Where(c => c.ItemDescriptionId.HasValue).Select(
                c => c.ItemDescriptionId).Distinct();

        IOrderedQueryable<ItemDescription> itemDescription =
            _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().Where(
                a => a.IsActive == true || itemDescriptionIds.Contains(a.ItemDescriptionId)).OrderBy(
                    d => d.Description);

        return itemDescription.Select(c=> new SearchItems{Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()});
    }
```

Comment: In your viewModel you initialize appointmentId. Is this a typo? You say you don't even have an AppointmentId in your ViewModel.

Comment: my bad... i didn't add it thinking that it isn't part of the issue. I removed some things like startDate and others which don't really deal with the getItems. but yes appointmentId is initialized.

Comment: My point was just that you set appointmentId but not itemdescriptionid in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your inital code wasn't querying the previously selected value was because your query `a.ItemDescriptionId == viewModel.ItemDescriptionId`, compares item description id, but in your View Model you only set appointment id. If you need item description id then make sure you initialize it.

```
var viewModel = new AppointmentViewModel
{
     AppointmentId = appointment.AppointmentId,
     ItemDescriptionId = appointment.ItemDescriptionId
};
```

Suggested refactoring:

```
private IEnumerable<SearchItems> GetItems(Guid lastId = new Guid())
{
    IOrderedQueryable<ItemDescription> items= _itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll();

    if(!items.Any())
        ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("No active {0} entered.", Kids.Resources.Entities.ItemDescription.EntityNamePlural));

    return items
        .OrderBy(c => c.Description).Where(a=>a.IsActive == true || a.ItemDescriptionId == lastId)
        .Select(c => new SearchItems {Text = c.Description, Value = c.ItemDescriptionId.ToString()});
}
```

It's silly to pass in the ViewModel when all your using it for is taking the necessary Guid. Then call it like

```
viewModel.Items= GetItems(appointment.ItemDescriptionId);
```

If you're query still isnt adding the correct item try debugging it like.

```
var testExists = itemDescriptionRepository.FindAll().FirstOrDefault(a.ItemDescriptionId == lastId);
```

If you're not finding it, and you're certain lastId is set correctly, it's probably a database issue.

Comment: I just tried this and now i get an error page stating: Could not convert from type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Int16'.

Comment: Where is the error? Is your itemDescriptionId a guid or an integer? The initial reason your code never queried correctly is you only set appointmentId in your viewmodel, then you compare against itemDescriptionId which is always null/the default value.

Comment: I believe that is the issue that the itemDescriptionId is always null and i just can't wrap my head around it. The error message i get is in my view page .cshtml file and the red line is: self.items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items));

Comment: ItemDescriptionId will always be null because you never set it anywhere. You never set in in your ViewModel and when you create these SearchItems the only values you create are Text and Value.

Comment: Since this code is looking at an edit page so the itemDescriptionId should've been set in the Create method correct? and whatever was created the edit page is feeding of it.

Comment: I meant your viewmodel never sets itemDescriptionId. I have no idea if its in your database or not. You'd need to examine that yourself.

Comment: just added the lines of what i have in the viewModel class regarding this in original post.

Comment: I really appreciate your help AFinkelstein, I was able to resolve the issue and it was basically using a different parameter - I used the "Appoinment" parameter which contained all the values and Id's of created items and i used it to reference and compare with the Item Description. I will post my changes anyhow. Thanks again!